# c# Regex several numbers with comma

Tags: c#

I would like to know how to get more than one comma with regex
I started with the string:

```
var str = "A:12,18,12 B:10";
```

now started with regex:

```
var reg = Regex.Matches(str,@"A:(\d+)\sB:(\d+)").cast<Match>().select(rg => new {
 A = rg.Groups[1].Value,
 B = rg.Groups[2].Value
}).ToList();
 foreach(var lop in reg)
 { 
   Console.Write(lop.A + "-" + lop.B);
 }
```

I am not good in regex but in B: everything works fine, in A: but not.
I think it's the comma
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the regex to

```
@"A:(\d+(,\d+)*)\sB:(\d+)
```

i.e., add zero or more repetitions (`*`) of `,\d+`.

If commas can appear in B as well:

```
@"A:(\d+(,\d+)*)\sB:(\d+(,\d+)*)
```

Comment: okay thanks,
but what if A has only 1 number, does it stay the same?

Comment: Yes, `(,\d+)*` means zero, one or more repetitions of `,\d+`. So, if zero repetitions the first `\d+` stays alone.

Comment: okay, thanks, my last question is how can I check if A has a `:` or not with regex

Comment: Append the optional operator `?` to `:` ==>  `A:?`

Comment: So like this `@"A:?(\d+(,\d+)*)\sB:(\d+)`

Comment: Yes. Note that the extra `()` might change the group number of B: